# configuring orientdb class level clusters on different nodes

Tags: orientdb2.2

I have got a problem in configuring the orientdb distributed cluster. Basically i have three orientdb servers instances on three different machines and i wants to have three clusters for a class and each cluster should be present on two different nodes.For that i have the `defaut-distributed-db-config.json` as below.

```
{
  "autoDeploy": true,
  "readQuorum": 1,
  "writeQuorum": "majority",
  "executionMode": "undefined",
  "readYourWrites": true,
  "newNodeStrategy": "static",
  "servers": {
    "*": "master"
  },
  "clusters": {
    "internal": {
    },
    "employee_0": { "servers": ["node0","node1"] },
    "employee_1": { "servers": ["node1","node2"] },
    "employee_2": { "servers": ["node2","node3"] },
    "*": { "servers": ["node1","<NEW_NODE>"  }
  }
}
```

So here i dont have any database already created before i start the services on all the three nodes. I have started all the nodes and all seems to be `OK`.When i created the database on `node1`, I have got exceptions on  other nodes as below.

```
2017-08-03 18:19:04:727 INFO   [node1]->[node2] Creating backup of cluster 'global' in directory: /tmp/orientdb/backup_global_user_1.zip... [OSy
ncClusterTask]Exception `3F3E8071` in storage `global`
com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OStorageException: Cluster employee_1 does not exist in database 'global'
        DB name="global"
```

so i have created the clusters `employee_0`,`employee_1` and `employee_2` on respective nodes(1,2 and 3) as below.

```
orientdb {db=global}> create cluster employee_0

Error: com.orientechnologies.orient.server.distributed.task.ODistributedOperationException: Quorum 3 not reached for request (id=0.29 task=command_sql(create cluster employee_0)). Elapsed=15002ms. No server in conflict. Received: 
 - mum105: 33
 - hyd107: waiting-for-response
 - ban106: 33
    DB name="global"
    DB name="global"
```

I have set the `writeQuorum` to `majority` in the config but it tries with 3.From where it is taking that 3 instead of 2. But i could see cluster `employee_0` already created on `node0` and `node1`. So i have proceeded to create the class once all the clusters created.

```
orientdb {db=global}> create class user cluster 33

Error: com.orientechnologies.orient.server.distributed.task.ODistributedOperationException: Quorum 3 not reached for request (id=0.295 task=command_sql(create class user cluster 33)). Elapsed=15015ms. No server in conflict. Received: 
 - mum105: 12
 - hyd107: waiting-for-response
 - ban106: 12
    DB name="global"
    DB name="global"
```

Even for this i got the same exception and again i could see class created.

```
|#   |NAME       |SUPER-CLASSES|CLUSTERS  

|10  |user       |             |user_0(33)
```

so i have moved on to insert a record into the class and not inserting.

```
orientdb {db=global}> insert into employee(id,name) values (1,'jhon')

Error: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.ORecordNotFoundException: The record with id '#33:0' was not found
    DB name="global"
    DB name="global"

Error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cluster 33 is null
```

Am i doing a mistake? any help would be appreciated. I'm stuck with these questions in mind.

1.Is there a correct approach  to setup  the distributed cluster as described above.

2.Why `Quorum 3` is being used when i set it to `majority`?

3.While inserting the record it says `RECORD #33:0 not found`. what is wrong here?